# Joomla meta description on facebook

Tags: joomla, meta-tags, joomla3.0

How can I change meta description for Joomla website when the website shared on facebook ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System** > **Global Configuration**. Under the **Site** tab you should see **Metadata Settings**. You might have to scroll down a bit, depending on your screen resolution.
Here, you can change the description and keywords for the site. Whatever you put in the description here should also show up when you share the site on Facebook.

Edit: You can use this extension, which converts Joomla's regular Meta Data to Open Graph, which is what Facebook and other social media sites are using when you share the website:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/simple-facebook-meta/

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, When I share website the metadata dose not appear ?

Comment: hmm.. From a quick Google search I found this extension: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/open-graph/20596

It seems Facebook's not a fan of the meta-description integrated in vanilla Joomla...

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to a nifty little extension I often use to solve this issue ;-)